# Spring boot MySQL application

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I have come to you because for the past 1 day I have been stuck on a probably innocuous problem. I am creating an application from Spring Boot and Mysql. Everything seems functional when launching the application because the database is created correctly. My problem is that the tables are not created... I can't find my error

Voici des bouts de mon application :

pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.tracker</groupId>
    <artifactId>EsportTracker</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>EsportTracker</name>
    <description>Tracker for videos games</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties :

```
#tomcat properties
server.port=7070

#jdbc properties

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/esportDatabase?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=*****
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

#hibernate properties

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

and here is my first entity :

```
package com.tracker.EsportTracker.entities;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import com.tracker.EsportTracker.models.Username;

@Entity
public class User implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idUser;
    private String lastNameUser;
    private String firstNameUser;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private Username username;
    private String password;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date dateNaissanceUser;
    private String emailUser;
    private long phoneNumberUser;

    public User() { 
    
    }
    
    public User(String lastNameUser, String firstNameUser, Username username, String password, 
            Date dateNaissanceUser, String emailUser, long phoneNumberUser) {
        this.lastNameUser = lastNameUser;
        this.firstNameUser = firstNameUser;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.dateNaissanceUser = dateNaissanceUser;
        this.emailUser = emailUser;
        this.phoneNumberUser = phoneNumberUser;
    }
    
    public Long getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }
    public void setIdUser(Long idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }
    public String getlastNameUser() {
        return lastNameUser;
    }
    public void setlastNameUser(String lastNameUser) {
        this.lastNameUser = lastNameUser;
    }
    public String getfirstNameUser() {
        return firstNameUser;
    }
    public void setfirstNameUser(String firstNameUser) {
        this.firstNameUser = firstNameUser;
    }
    public Username getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(Username username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public Date getDateNaissanceUser() {
        return dateNaissanceUser;
    }
    public void setDateNaissanceUser(Date dateNaissanceUser) {
        this.dateNaissanceUser = dateNaissanceUser;
    }
    public String getEmailUser() {
        return emailUser;
    }
    public void setEmailUser(String emailUser) {
        this.emailUser = emailUser;
    }
    public long getphoneNumberUtisateur() {
        return phoneNumberUser;
    }
    public void setphoneNumberUtisateur(long phoneNumberUtisateur) {
        this.phoneNumberUser = phoneNumberUtisateur;
    }
}
```

Thanking you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all remove

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

from maven `pom.xml` , because from spring boot 3, use `jakarta` instead of `javax` you dont need to provide it dependency because it has already provided by `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`

Second point add one more annotation to the entity class, something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {...}
```

The last one be sure that all imports from project that start with `javax` will be replaced to `jakarta` for example:

`import javax.persistence.Column;`  to

`import jakarta.persistence.Column;`